# decl.h error compiling with turbo c and dev C++

Tags: c, dos

I'm relatively new to the C world, I studied it at school, but that was ages ago.
Now I'm interested again, especially cause I have a goal to achieve, I have to program some not-so-new instrument, a DSO from tektronix, with a GPib card, working under DOS.

I found some info online, but when I try to compile the program, I get errors with the `decl.h` header, I took the header from the national instruments software pack, I will append it below.

The errors are all relating missing simbols (initializers) before funtions (under dev c++) and errors about type mismatch (under Turbo C 2.0)

Can someone help me? I took the header as a black box, do not know what it does, I just call some functions in the program.

Header code that give problems:

```
/* Function prototypes */

extern int _far _cdecl ibask(int handle, int option, int _far *retval);

extern int _far _cdecl ibbna(int handle, char _far *bdname);

extern int _far _cdecl ibcac(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibclr(int handle);

extern int _far _cdecl ibcmd(int handle, void _far *buffer, long cnt);

extern int _far _cdecl ibcmda(int handle, void _far *buffer, long cnt);

extern int _far _cdecl ibconfig(int handle, int option, int value);

extern int _far _cdecl ibdev(int boardID, int pad, int sad, int tmo, int eot, int eos);

extern int _far _cdecl ibdma(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibeos(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibeot(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibevent(int handle, short _far *event);

extern int _far _cdecl ibfind(char _far *bdname);

extern int _far _cdecl ibgts(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibist(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl iblines(int handle, short _far *lines);

extern int _far _cdecl ibln(int handle, int padval, int sadval, short _far *listenflag);

extern int _far _cdecl ibloc(int handle);

extern int _far _cdecl ibonl(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibpad(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibpct(int handle);

extern int _far _cdecl ibppc(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibrd(int handle, void _far *buffer, long cnt);

extern int _far _cdecl ibrda(int handle, void _far *buffer, long cnt);

extern int _far _cdecl ibrdf(int handle, char _far *flname);

extern int _far _cdecl ibrpp(int handle, char _far *ppr);

extern int _far _cdecl ibrsc(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibrsp(int handle, char _far *spr);

extern int _far _cdecl ibrsv(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibsad(int handle, int v);

extern int _far _cdecl ibsic(int handle);

extern int _far _cdecl ibsre(int handle, int v);

extern void _far _cdecl ibsrq(void (_far *func)(void));

extern int _far _cdecl ibstop(int handle);

extern int _far _cdecl ibtmo(int handle, int v);

extern void _far _cdecl ibtrap(int  mask, int mode);

extern int _far _cdecl ibtrg(int handle);

extern int _far _cdecl ibwait(int handle, int mask);

extern int _far _cdecl ibwrt(int handle, void _far *buffer, long cnt);

extern int _far _cdecl ibwrta(int handle, void _far *buffer, long cnt);

extern int _far _cdecl ibwrtf(int handle, char _far *flname);

extern int _far _cdecl ibpoke(int handle, int option, int value);

extern int _far _cdecl ibdiag(int handle, void _far *buffer, long cnt);

extern int _far _cdecl ibxtrc(int handle, void _far *buffer, long cnt);

extern int _far _cdecl ibwrtkey(int handle, void _far *buffer, int  cnt);

extern int _far _cdecl ibrdkey(int handle, void _far *buffer, int cnt);

extern void _far _cdecl AllSpoll(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist, short _far *resultlist);

extern void _far _cdecl DevClear(int boardID, Addr4882_t address);

extern void _far _cdecl DevClearList(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist);

extern void _far _cdecl EnableLocal(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist);

extern void _far _cdecl EnableRemote(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist);

extern void _far _cdecl FindLstn(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *padlist, Addr4882_t _far *resultlist, int limit);

extern void _far _cdecl FindRQS(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist, short _far *result);

extern void _far _cdecl PPoll(int boardID, short _far *result);

extern void _far _cdecl PPollConfig(int boardID, Addr4882_t address, int dataLine, int lineSense);

extern void _far _cdecl PPollUnconfig(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist);

extern void _far _cdecl PassControl(int boardID, Addr4882_t address);

extern void _far _cdecl RcvRespMsg(int boardID, void _far *buffer, long cnt, int termination);

extern void _far _cdecl ReadStatusByte(int boardID, Addr4882_t address, short _far *result);

extern void _far _cdecl Receive(int boardID, Addr4882_t address, void _far *buffer, long cnt, int termination);

extern void _far _cdecl ReceiveSetup(int boardID, Addr4882_t address);

extern void _far _cdecl ResetSys(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist);

extern void _far _cdecl Send(int boardID, Addr4882_t address, void _far *buffer, long datacnt, int eotmode);

extern void _far _cdecl SendCmds(int boardID, void _far *buffer, long cnt);

extern void _far _cdecl SendDataBytes(int boardID, void _far *buffer, long cnt, int eotmode);

extern void _far _cdecl SendIFC(int boardID);

extern void _far _cdecl SendLLO(int boardID);

extern void _far _cdecl SendList(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist, void _far *buffer, long datacnt, int eotmode);

extern void _far _cdecl SendSetup(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist);

extern void _far _cdecl SetRWLS(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist);

extern void _far _cdecl TestSRQ(int boardID, short _far *result);

extern void _far _cdecl TestSys(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist, short _far *resultlist);

extern void _far _cdecl Trigger(int boardID, Addr4882_t address);

extern void _far _cdecl TriggerList(int boardID, Addr4882_t _far *addrlist);

extern void _far _cdecl WaitSRQ(int boardID, short _far *result);

extern void _far _cdecl GotoMultAddr(int boardID,
                                     unsigned short type,
                                     unsigned short (_far *addrfunc)(),
                                     unsigned short (_far *spollfunc)());

extern void _far _cdecl GenerateREQT(int boardID, unsigned short addr);

extern void _far _cdecl GenerateREQF(int boardID, unsigned short addr);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Do not use ancient compilers. C has evolved in the last 16 years and using an ancient dialect is really a bad idea. Chances are your card is supported in Linux, so you can use the modern gcc with a C (or C++) compiler.

Comment: The declarations you present appear to use extensions specific to some particular (but unknown) compiler -- most notably qualifiers `_far` and `_cdecl`, which are all over the place.  You can probably `#define`ing them to something appropriate to the compiler you're using now, but I'm uncertain what the appropriate alternatives would be (unless nothing -- you could always try just defining them to empty strings).

Comment: Dev C++ is not a compiler. And gcc is not a 16-bit compiler

Comment: `missing simbols (initializers) before funtions (under dev c++)` That's probably about `_far` which no 32b compiler would have any reason to support nowadays. `errors about type mismatch (under Turbo C 2.0)` That's probably about something in the code you didn't show, the code that actually calls those functions.

Comment: Can you add the errors?